# Realm query for all objects with RealmList containing less then a given number of elements

Tags: realm

Is there a way to make a query along the lines of the following in Realm?

realm.where(Foo.class).equalTo("bar.id").lessThen("baz.size", count).findAll()

Namely need to find all instances of Foo that have a Bar with a given id, and a RealmList of Baz containing no more then count elements.

I see the isEmpty, and isNotEmpty, but no direct means to do the above.

Looking at this for more convenience then necessity as I can easily parse the results of findAll.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a way to make a query like that. Not a bad idea though.

Comment: Query with `RealmList` size is currently not supported :(

Comment: I added this [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3414#issuecomment-245477746) for it though for future reference, because this is a good idea